# How to occupy the app bottom with an image?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, interface-builder, autolayout

In Xcode I have placed 2 buttons at the top and 1 image (in **Aspect Fill** mode) at the bottom:

[image: screenshot 1]

All 3 elements are center-aligned.

For the buttons I have added 20 px constraints to the sides and top and they seem to be placed well now.

However I can not figure out, which constraints to use - to nail the image at the bottom and make it occupy the most space there.

I have tried the following:

- Center-aligned the image
- 20 px constraints to left, bottom and right
- More or equal to 20 px constraing to the above button

Still warnings for the image placement are displayed by the Interface Builder:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Will it always be the same image, or at least always the same-sized image?

Comment: It will be 4 same-sized images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set an Aspect Ratio constraint for the image so that Xcode knows how large it will be

Comment: That has fixed it! How does Xcode know my aspect ratio, can I use other-sized images at runtime? And should I delete the other constraints?

Comment: You can use other images, as long as the image is set to aspect fit. You do not need to remove the other constraints, as they have to do more with positioning.